# Devise login form within Bootstrap Modal, prevent close and redirect after wrong login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I have a devise login form built into a bootstrap modal. Login works great. However, if a user enters the wrong login information the modal window closes and redirects. How can I prevent this default action happening in rails, and keep the modal open to include the error messages.
Thanks!

Code:

```
<div class="modal" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
     <div><%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email" %>
     </div>
     <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-extra">
     <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me, class: "remember-check" %> <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "remember" %>
     <% end -%>
    </div>
   <div><%= f.submit "Log in via email", :class => "btn btn-email" %></div>
   <%= render partial: 'layouts/flash_messages', flash: flash %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw you mentioned 'redirect'. Redirect to where? You can do a respond to js and display the error message through javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to do some custom javascript.  That can be done a couple ways.

1. Remove the submit button and just have an input button with an id.  When that is clicked, send the request to your registrations controller to render back an ajax response.  Display the message if there is an error, redirect to the login page if it returns a session.
2. Prevent the default action and then handle the request through ajax, if you get a valid session back allow the default submit action to continue.  Otherwise display the message.